# Transformation rule for a sum of functions

Tags: replacement, rule

When applying the rule:

```
exp[c[x] + d[x] + e[x]] //. exp[a_[x] + b_[x]] -> exp[a[x]] + exp[b[x]]
```

I would like to get

```
exp[c[x]] + exp[d[x]] + exp[e[x]]
```

as a result. But instead I get the initial expression unchanged.

The rule only works for expressions with two additives:

```
exp[c[x] + d[x] + e[x]] //. exp[a_[x] + b_[x]] -> exp[a[x]] + exp[b[x]]
```

How can I make it work for a general case?

Comment: I have to ask:  Do you want to end up with `Exp[c[x]]+Exp[d[x]+Exp[e[x]]` or `Exp[c[x]]*Exp[d[x]*Exp[e[x]]`?  If by `exp` you really mean `Exp`, then the former is not the proper expansion while the latter is.

Comment: I want to end-up with `exp[c[x]]+exp[d[x]]+exp[e[x]]`. `exp` was supposed to mean "expected value" for some random distribution. Initially I used `\[DoubleStruckE]` for that function, but converted it to lower-case `exp` to post my question here.

Comment: OK.  Got it.  Sorry about about my wrong inference..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers do not explain *why* your rule doesn't work. They also don't capture the spirit of your question, in my opinion. I will use arbitrary functions so as not to be distracted by incidentals.

## Why doesn't the "obvious" rule work?

First, let's explain why `f[c[x] + d[x] + e[x]] //. f[a_[x] + b_[x]] -> f[a[x]] + exp[b[x]]` doesn't do what you want it to. You are wanting to use the `Flat` attribute of the `Plus` function to "break" `f` over addition, because you reason that since `Plus[b, c, d]===Plus[b, Plus[c, d]]`, then `f[Plus[b[x], c[x], d[x]]]/.f[p_[x] + q_[x]] -> f[b[x]]+f[c[x]+d[x]]`. In fact, you may have noticed that it *does* work without the functions:

```
a+b+c/.x_+y_->{{x},{y}}
```

> ```
> {{a}, {b + c}}
> ```

The `Blank` pattern—and *only* the `Blank` pattern—is treated in a special way when used on `Flat` functions like `Plus`, because `Blank` is given a special meaning within `Flat` functions in the sense that it can match like `f[__]` (if it’s able to). In particular, a `Blank` pattern can match any sequence of arguments of `f[a, b, c, ...]` when `f` is flat. To drive home the point, we can use `ReplaceList` to list all of the different possible ways to match the pattern:

```
SetAttributes[f, Flat];
ReplaceList[f[b, c, d], f[x_, y_] -> {{x}, {y}}]
```

> ```
> {{{f[b]},{f[c,d]}}, {{f[b,c]},{f[d]}}, {{b},{f[c,d]}}, {{f[b,c]},{d}}}
> ```

However, `p_[x]`, or any other pattern, is *not* endowed with this same special meaning within `Flat` functions, and so `f[p_[x], q_[x], ...]` has the effect of annihilating `p_`’s special abilities within `Flat` functions.

Here's the rule for non-`Blank` patterns (as of v11.3): If a pattern has to *unflatten* a flat function in order to match, then the pattern will not match. On the other hand, if a `Blank` pattern needs to unflatten a flat function in order to match, it will.

## How can we make a rule that works?

### The general case

Here's the general case: Suppose `g` is any function and `f` is `Flat`. We are interested in transforming `g[f[c[x], d[x], e[x]]]` into `f[g[c[x]], g[f[d[x], e[x]]]` in a single step. Thus,

```
SetAttributes[f, Flat];
g[f[c[x], d[x], e[x]]] //. g[f[a_[x], b_]] :> f[g[a[x]], g[f[b]]]
```

> ```
> f[g[c[x]], g[d[x]], g[f[e[x]]]]
> ```

Notice that the final result has an inner `f`, because we have no rule for when `g` has only a single argument. In other words, it did exactly what we asked it, but not more.

### The specific case of `Plus`

There is nothing special about `Plus`. Again, for any function `g`, we want to transform `g[c[x] + d[x] + e[x]]` into `g[c[x]] + g[d[x] + e[x]]` in one step. Thus,

```
g[c[x] + d[x] + e[x]] //. g[a_[x] + b_] :> g[a[x]] + g[b]
```

> ```
>  g[c[x]] + g[d[x]] + g[e[x]]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Many possibilities exist.  One is

```
Exp[c[x] + d[x] + e[x]] /. Exp[z_] :> Total@Exp@(List @@ z)
(* E^c[x] + E^d[x] + E^e[x] *)
```

Another is

```
Exp[c[x] + d[x] + e[x]] /. Exp @ z_ :> Exp /@ z
```

Answer (score 0):

A *slightly* different implementation.

```
Exp[c[x] + d[x] + e[x]] /. Exp[HoldPattern@Plus[x__]] :> Plus @@ Exp[{x}]
```

> E^c[x] + E^d[x] + E^e[x]